# Linked list and sparse matrix in C

Tags: c, linked-list, sparse-matrix

I need to represent a sparse matrix using liked list in C:

The structure definition is the following;

```
typedef struct matrix{
  struct matrix *right;
  struct matrix *below;
  int rowptr, colptr;
  double val;
}Matrix;
```

I know that right is pointing to the next non-zero element of the row (below points to the non-zero element of the column).

I need to define this functions:

1. Matrix* initiate(void), which uses stdin to read the non-zero element from a .txt file (which only contains the non-zero values).
2. void print(Matrix*), it prints the matrix using stdout.
3. Matrix* add(Matrix*, Matrix*);
4. void set_elemnt(Matrix* A, int i, int j, double x): assigns A(i,j)=x.
5. double get_element(Matrix * A, int i, int j); returns A(i,j).

I don't know hot to define the header cells (wich contain nothing), the other cells represents the non-zero values. 
This image  in this link represent an idea of what I have to do:

[image]

What I have so far:

```
Matrix* initiate(void){
  Matrix *A=malloc(sizeof(*A));

  A->rowptr=rowptr;
  A->colptr=colptr;

  A->right=malloc(rowptr * sizeof(*rowptr->right));
  A->below=malloc(n * sizeof(*n->col));

  return A;
}
```

For the header (the one containing nothing), I tried to do this, but I have no idea if it is useful:

```
Matrix* initiate_1(void){
   Matrix *A=malloc(sizeof(*A));
   A->rowptr=-1;
   A->colptr=-1;
   A->val=nan;
   A->right=A;
   A->below=A;
}
```

To add matrix:

```
Matrix* add(Matrix*,Matrix*){
   int i;
   Matrix *C = initiate(); //I don't know what to put here
   for (int i = 0; ; i++) { //don't know what to put in the middle space
                            // don't know what to put here
   }
}
```

Also, I think I can create a matrix with zeros only, but I'm not sure on how I can do that and if it is of any help.
I would appreciate if you could help me with this, I barely understand data structures. Thank you!

Comment: Do not post links. And don't post images if avoidable. Your question has to be self-contained. As far as I see, you did quite a lot correct here (not casting `void *`, `sizeof(*<pointer>)`, ... Maybe you should think first what you actually want to accomplish, refine this and **then** think about how to implement it.

Comment: It seems someone else had the same homework in January: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28000250/creating-a-sparse-matrix-using-linked-lists-in-c

Comment: But I think that this are not the same functions, is it posible to help me a little with the definitions?

Comment: You diagram appears to show R[n] and C[n] as non-sparse arrays. If so they'd just contain a single `Matrix*`.

Comment: What it is the purpose of `initiate_1()` ? It returns nothing so you won't be able to access it from anywhere else, this is a memory leak.

Comment: I thought that it would create the header cells :/